# xpath query not returning data

Tags: php, xpath, scrape

i'm trying to figure out how to get a attribute from a specific div on a web page, but my query isn't returning anything. I'm assuming my query is just wrong.

i'm trying to get the **data-original** url from this div:

```
<div 
class="p-dynamic-image vox-lazy-load lazy-loaded” 
data-original="https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Bv7HhgyCscPLXrx2qHPzo8dlU4g=/0x0:7015x4677/2050x1367/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/46369294/RzrFirefly_01_DA.0.0.jpg” 
style="background-image: url(https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Bv7HhgyCscPLXrx2qHPzo8dlU4g=/0x0:7015x4677/2050x1367/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/46369294/RzrFirefly_01_DA.0.0.jpg);">
</div>
```

my code:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($page_dom);
$image = $xpath->query("//div[@class='p-dynamic-image vox-lazy-load lazy-loaded']/@data-original")->value;
echo $image . "<br />";
```

but this isn't returning anything.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it should be:

```
<?php

$html_string ='<div 
class="p-dynamic-image vox-lazy-load lazy-loaded"
data-original="https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/..." style="...">
</div>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

echo $xpath->query(
    '//div[@class="p-dynamic-image vox-lazy-load lazy-loaded"]/@data-original')
        ->item(0)->value; // https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/...
```

Comment: thanks, this does get the url. But I wanted to do it without getAttribute, is that possible? or is there no work around?

Comment: @felipsmartins his question was how to do it *without* `getAttribute`.  In other words, in pure xpath.

Comment: @nomistic Oh, I see. You're right! Scott you should be mark answer from nomistic as right answear because it solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Okay try using this (with query instead of xpath)

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($page_dom);

$results=$xml->query("//div[@class='p-dynamic-image vox-lazy-load lazy-loaded']/@data-original")->value;

foreach ($results as $image) {
    echo $image;

 }
```

Edit again:  Note the method you were using before would work for SimpleXML, but for DOM it seems you need to do it within a foreach

Comment: hmm my echo still doesn't print anything?

Comment: unfortunately not, still nothing is printed.

Comment: you may also need to put the `-->value` back (with the foreach) sorry.   If not, are you able to get anything at all with your xpath?

Comment: when I add the ->value back I get: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), and yeah I'm using the xpath to grab other things fine. it's just this piece of content i'm struggling with

Comment: hmm, now it throws a fatal error: Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context, it doesn't like the foreach loop

Comment: okay, I think it should be fixed, and this should get rid of the fatal error

Comment: fatal error is gone, but it's still not working. I'm changing $xml->xpath to $xpath->query, do you reckon thats the reason why?

Comment: try it with simpxml as I changed it;  this *should* work

Comment: produces a warning and a fatal error, simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 & Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object

Comment: ok, back to dom (I don't feel like fishing out the syntax).  One more try, this time with query ()